# How to deploy a Julia function in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, julia, packagecompiler.jl

I need to execute a data-intensive algorithm in AWS Lambda to reduce costs. The main reason is that the application won't be heavily used.

In Python, such algorithm executes an analysis in 5 seconds, while Julia does it in 0.8 when using a [SysImage](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/sysimages.html), so there's a clear advantage.

After developing a custom runtime as explained in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html), containerizing the Julia code with Docker and testing it locally, I tried to deploy it at AWS Lambda without success.

Firstly, the error log showed problems loading the SysImage:

```
/var/task/CustomImage.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

This was fixed by increasing Lambda's memory.

The next issue arised was:

```
ERROR: Unable to find compatible target in system image.
```

I thought it related to Julia trying to find the target architecture of its runtime, so I updated the SysImage creation function to take into account a x86_64 arch.

Created the SysImage, deployed everything again, and now the Lambda fails without errors.

---

### Relevant code:

This function creates the SysImage:

```
using PackageCompiler

create_sysimage(["DataFrames", "CSV", "GeoDataFrames", "SpatialDependence", "Statistics", "LisaLambda"];
                sysimage_path="CustomImage.so",
                precompile_execution_file="precompile/precompile.jl",
                cpu_target="generic")
```

My `bootstrap` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is called by the lambda execution environment when it
# receives the very first invocation request.

cd /var/task

/usr/local/julia/bin/julia --sysimage=CustomImage.so --project=. main.jl
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
# AWS provided base image (Amazon Linux 2)
# It includes Lambda Runtime Emulator for testing locally.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2

# Download and install Julia
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN yum install -y tar gzip \
 && curl -LO https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.9/julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
 && tar xf julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
 && rm julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
 && ln -s julia-1.9.2 julia

# Dependency
RUN yum install -y gcc make \
 && curl -LO https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.9.tar.gz \
 && tar xf v1.2.9.tar.gz \
 && rm v1.2.9.tar.gz \
 && cd zlib-1.2.9 \
 && ./configure; make; make install \
 && ln -sf ./lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so.1 
# && ln -sf ./lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib/libz.so.1

# Install application
WORKDIR /var/task

# Use a special depot path to store precompiled binaries
ENV JULIA_DEPOT_PATH /var/task/.julia

# Instantiate project and precompile packages
COPY Manifest.toml .
COPY Project.toml .
RUN /usr/local/julia/bin/julia --project=. -e "using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate();"
RUN /usr/local/julia/bin/julia --project=. -e "using Pkg; Pkg.precompile();"

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Uncomment this line to allow more precompilation in lamdbda just in case.
# That's because /var/task is a read-only path during runtime.
ENV JULIA_DEPOT_PATH /tmp/.julia:/var/task/.julia

# Install bootstrap script
WORKDIR /var/runtime
COPY bootstrap .

# Create an empty extensions directory
WORKDIR /opt/extensions

# Shared libraries:
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1

WORKDIR /lib
COPY CustomImage.so .
WORKDIR /opt/lib
COPY CustomImage.so .

# Which module/function to call?
CMD [ "LisaLambda.handle_event" ]
```

The Julia algorithm also uses some csv and gpkg files stored along with the code.

The project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── bootstrap
├── CustomImage.so
├── data
│   ├── fileA.gpkg
│   └── fileB.csv
├── Dockerfile
├── main.jl
├── Manifest.toml
├── precompile
│   ├── create_sysimage.jl
│   └── precompile.jl
├── Project.toml
└── src
    ├── GeoData.jl
    ├── LisaLambda.jl
    └── Moran.jl
```

Comment: what does "fail without error" mean

Comment: The log just says: `Task timed out after 3.00 seconds` with no further explanation.

Comment: what happens when you increase lambda limit to eg 30 seconds? Looks like a cold start issue to me.